# Motor Driver - Microcontroller-less and no IC chips available

Tags: led, circuit-design, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am looking to control a DC motor with the use of an IR-LED detection circuit.

I am hoping that when the IR-LED circuit detects a wall approaching, the robot will pivot and move towards the other wall in a 45degree angle or so.

However, I need help driving my motor.

I do not have a microcontroller and no IC chips so I can't use a L293 or anything like that.

What is the best way to create a motor driver with the IR-LED used for switching?

Comment: I sure hope your motor has brushes. Use transistors.

Comment: So, should I build a H-bridge?

Comment: I would recommend no, since it would be more complicated and your sensors don't need to ever need to make your bot go in reverse, nor can they easily decide when to reverse. Just faster or slower on one side should be enough to veer away. Even easier is to have just go or no go instead of variable speed. That would just be one power transistor per motor.

Comment: Okay, so what's the best option to build? Just trying to get an idea. Do you have any examples or schematics I could implement?

Comment: Look for simple line follower robot circuits. When sensor on the right is brighter, apply power to the right motor. Same for left. Might need to add extra complexity to handle equal brightness on both sides later so it doesn't run perfectly straight into a wall.

Comment: How is this different from your [other question that was closed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492439/robot-wall-avoiding-plinko-robot)?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to make a difference between "Power Driving," "Motor Controlling," and "Robot Decision Making"

1. For power driving of a DC motor that needs to rotate in both directions, you need a circuit based on the H-Bridge concept.

   - To make an H-Bridge you can have different solutions based on your requirements. If you need speed control you can use 4 transistors either BJTs of FETs are usable.
   - If you just need direction control (at full speed), you can use 4 SPST relay in the place of transistors, or you can use 2 SPDT relays. Because either leg of an H-Bridge consists of a high-side driver and a low-side driver which never turn on at the same time, you can use an SPDT relay.
   - There is also a little trick that you can use 2 SPDT relays to control the direction and use just one low-side OR high-side transistor to control the speed. It's preferred to use a PWM signal to control the speed.
2. Controlling the direction is easy with a single binary signal, but, as I mention above, controlling the speed needs more complex signal generation which is a little difficult without a micro-controller. You can use some old methods like 555 to generate the signal.
3. About decision making: You said that you need a 45 degree angle. It depends on the robot mechanics but I think you can use basic logic for that, something like flip-flops and basic gates, but in simple systems maybe a few transistors are also enough. As I said, it depends on the physics of it.

Comment: The requirement of 45-degree-to-the wall is likely the most difficult part of this project.

Comment: @glen_geek Yeah, you are right, and as I said we need more information about the mechanics of the problem.